# converting array into customized xml

Tags: xml, arrays, json, coldfusion

So, I have following array from the query :

(findpercentage is the name of the cfquery I have used)

```
<cfset pieData = ArrayNew(1)>

    <cfset dataItem =[ 'Open', '#findpercentage.OPENS#' ]>
    <cfset ArrayAppend(pieData, dataItem)>  

    <cfset dataItem =[ 'Bounce', '#findpercentage.BOUNCE#' ]>
    <cfset ArrayAppend(pieData, dataItem)>  

    <cfset dataItem =[ 'Deferred', '#findpercentage.DEFERRED_EVENT#' ]>
    <cfset ArrayAppend(pieData, dataItem)>  

    <cfset dataItem =[ 'Dropped', '#findpercentage.DROPPED#' ]>
    <cfset ArrayAppend(pieData, dataItem)>  

    <cfset dataItem =[ 'Delivered', '#findpercentage.Delivered#' ]>
    <cfset ArrayAppend(pieData, dataItem)>

    <cfset dataItem =[ 'Processed', '#findpercentage.Processed#' ]>
    <cfset ArrayAppend(pieData, dataItem)>      

    <cfset dataItem =[ 'Spamreport', '#findpercentage.Spamreport#' ]>
    <cfset ArrayAppend(pieData, dataItem)>
```

The array looks like the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0BmZ.png):

The array size can keep on growing or shrinking (For example, there can be 2 arrays sometime and 20 sometime).

Is there a way, from the above array, I can generate an XML like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <value>31.4164</value>
        <label>Open</label>
        <colour>FFFF10AA</colour>
    </item>
    <item>
        <value>3.2240</value>
        <label>Bounce</label>
        <colour>FFAA0AAA</colour>
    </item>
    <item>
        <value>0.2430</value>
        <label>Deferred</label>
        <colour>FF5505AA</colour>
    </item>
    <item>
        <value>1.2799</value>
        <label>Dropped</label>
        <colour>FF0000AA</colour>
    </item>
    <item>
        <value>31.5584</value>
        <label>Delivered</label>
        <colour>FF0000AA</colour>
    </item>
    <item>
        <value>32.2290</value>
        <label>Processed</label>
        <colour>FF0000AA</colour>
    </item>
    <item>
        <value>0.0217</value>
        <label>Spamreport</label>
        <colour>FF0000AA</colour>
    </item>
</root>
```

I will also need to figure out a way to generate unique color which I have hardcoded at this point of time in the `color` tag.

Reason I am converting it into XML is because the tool [here](http://www.geckoboard.com/developers/custom-widgets/widget-types/pie-chart) understands only XML or JSON.

Please let me know.

Result of SerializeJSON on my cfquery with name `findpercentage`:

```
{
    "COLUMNS": [
        "TOTAL_EVENTS",
        "OPENS",
        "BOUNCE",
        "DEFERRED_EVENT",
        "DROPPED",
        "DELIVERED",
        "PROCESSED",
        "SPAMREPORT"
    ],
    "DATA": [
        [
            267526,
            31.4164,
            3.224,
            0.243,
            1.2799,
            31.5584,
            32.229,
            0.0217
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why convert to XML? If you use `serializeJSON()` and pass it the array, it should be in the format you need.

Comment: @ScottStroz I can use `serializeJSON()` as well, I have posted the results in my updated question. You mean I should pass the results to array and append just like I did above? Won't it generate an array then?

Comment: One of the nice things about ColdFusion is that if you run a query, each column of the result set is effectively a 1D array.  That in itself should save you some code, and you have a lot of code happening here.  In fact, you don't even need an array to create xml.  Just loop through the query.

Comment: I meant call `serializeJSON()` on the variable named `piedata`, not the query. You may need to massage the data to get it into a format you need, but I can guarantee, simply serializing a query will NOT work.

Comment: Okay, As @DanBracuk mentioned, I just created XML manually and was able to output it on my browser screen. Now figuring out to write it's contents in a file. Thanks

Comment: If given a choice between passing data via XML or JSON, I would pick JSON every day (and twice on Sundays). You can create the data structure in CF the same way you would in JavaScript and then simply call `serializeJSON()`. JSON is less verbose - which means less data being sent 'over the wire'. a JSON string is easier to 'build' than XML. If you already have the array of data that you need, converting that data into XML is more resource intensive on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had to create an xml file from query results.  Basically, I did it like this:  First, create a variable with the query data in a more or less properly structured format.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="data">
<BurnRecords>
<cfoutput query="AllData">
more code
</cfoutput>
</BurnRecords>
```

Next, create another variable with proper xml format

```
<cfxml casesensitive="yes" variable="xmldata">
<cfoutput>#Replace(data, chr(10) & chr(13) & chr(10) & chr(13), chr(10), "all")#</cfoutput>
</cfxml>
```

Finally, write the xml data to a file.

```
<cffile action="write" nameconflict="overwrite" file="#FileName#" output="#xmldata#">
```

**Edit begins here**

In retrospect, I appear to have overengineered it.  This would have probably sufficed.

```
<cfxml casesensitive="yes" variable="xmldata">
<BurnRecords>
<cfoutput query="AllData">
more code
</cfoutput>
</BurnRecords>
```

Comment: _"proper xml format"_ - eh? faffing with newlines has nothing to do with any "proper" XML format. If you're going to include a step like that (and it's almost certainly unnecessary) then you need to explain the intent and reason of the change.

Comment: The cfxml tag does a number of text replacements.  I don't know them all, but apostrophes are one of them.  On the page from which I copied the code, I was outputting the xmldata to a text area.  That was the motivation to replace the carraige returns.